# Filter variables not showing for users

Tags: camunda

I have a simple filter available for all users which displays some variables in the tasklist.
It works for me and another account (both have all the rights as admin) but it doesn't work for my users.
They can see the filters and they work, but the variables are not displayed.

Is there an authorization or something that I am forgetting ?

I'm using 7.6.0 if that is of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I needed to add the READ_INSTANCE permission in the Process Definition Authorizations to my users' group, and now it works. Hope this may help someone !